# how can i emit data to other client (user) using socket.io?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, socket.io

I am sending data to all clients but it only APPEND on sender's Message body. In this case, real-time data is only working on sender only but i need to work on every connected users.

After reading the documentation it says, BROADCASTING could be the solution but its not showing for sender(Which means OK) But that also not showing for other connected receivers.

> > Custom.js

```
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000/");
    $.ajax({
     url: 'sent',
     type: 'POST',
     data: {
      msg: 'Some message'
     },
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (data) {
      if (data.message) {
        socket.emit('send', {
         msg: data.msgResult
        });
        socket.on('msgResult', result => {
         $(".msgDiv").append(result);
        });
      }
     }
    });
```

> > App.js

```
const app = express();
const http = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
console.log('Socket.io connected...');
socket.on('send', (data) => {
socket.emit('msgResult', data.msg);
});
socket.on('disconnect', () => {
console.log("A socket Discounted ..");
});
});
```

I want to append data to all connected users including sender too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send message to all connected sockets you can use

```
io.sockets.emit('msgResult', 'data');
```

and if you want to send message to all connected sockets except sender, use

```
socket.broadcast.emit('msgResult', 'data');
```

Comment: Not working. By the way, i edited few lines of code. i hope it might help.

Comment: do you see `data` when writing ```socket.on('send', data => console.log(data)```? in both client and server side?

Comment: Ya.. I saw in both side. But it only shows in sender's console.

Comment: what is your socket io client and server version? i used client 2.0.3 and server 2.1.1 and only replaced your `socket.emit('msgResult', data.msg);` with `io.sockets.emit('msgResult', data.msg);` and it worked completely fine

Answer (score 0):

*your index.js for socket server should have*
//webServerPort= localhost:3000

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
let constAppServer = server.listen(webServerPort);
let io = socketServer(constAppServer);
app.set('socket',io);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('connection opened');

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });

    socket.on('udagent',function(msg){
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
    });
});
```

*this is your event.js when you want to send a event to frontend*

```
const testFunction =(req,res)=> {
    let io = req.app.get('socket');
    io.emit('dashboard_event', { "totalMin": data });
}
```

Comment: I understand your solution. But this is not that,  I want. My message submission through other route file which is completely alright as well as I can fetch data through app. Js file using socket. But why it only work for sender? It should work for all connected receivers.

Comment: hey brother, can you tell me how can get it on BROADCAST in your event.js section ?

Comment: thats not possible as broadcasting event triggers and will pass to all the sockets connected , only excluding from whom the event the was fired, meaning the sender

Answer (score 0):

i had api for broadcasting my admin notifications to all the agents under me by creating and passing this api

```
const broadCastUpdates =(req,res)=> {
    const {message} = req.body
    let io = req.app.get('socket');
    io.broadcast.emit('broadCastToAgents', { 'data':message });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found my answer. it was a simple mistake which takes a lot of time.

> custom.js

```
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000/");
$.ajax({
     url: 'sent',
     type: 'POST',
     data: {
      msg: 'Some message'
     },
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (data) {
      if (data.message) {
        socket.emit('send', {
         msg: data.msgResult
        });
      }
    }
});

socket.on('msgResult', result => {
$(".msgDiv").append(result);
});
```

> App.js

```
const app = express();
const http = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
console.log('Socket.io connected...');
socket.on('send', (data) => {
socket.emit('msgResult', data.msg);
});
socket.on('disconnect', () => {
console.log("A socket Discounted ..");
});
});
```

i just plug out my **msgResult** from ajax submission. That's it.